# Error in Xcode simulator screen in older iOS version

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using iOS 14.4 in simulator to test my application, but when I try to run the application on a older version of iOS (12.1 or 12.4) the simulator screen look like this:

[image: iPhone XR - iOS 12.1]

I'm using Xcode 12.4 in macOS Catalina.

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB

Comment: Cool! Looks like a graphics issue. (Also looks like blue jeans.) File a bug with Apple, I’d say.

Comment: BTW you might try another graphics setting in the simulator app.